# method to convert a int into a binary format in C without itoa?

Tags: c, radix

how can i convert a integer with radix 10 to a binary string with C without having the itoa function?

Comment: An integer (`int`, etc.) _is_ in binary. Do you want to convert a string?

Comment: Please give an example of what you're looking for, as your question isn't clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Comment: Example input and expected output would make everything about this question clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print a '0' if the number is even or '1' if it is even, then divide by 2 and recurse. Only the other way around ... or something like that.

Example with 13

```
    13 is odd  so print 1 and divide by 2 giving 6
     6 is even so print 0 and divide by 2 giving 3
     3 is odd  so print 1 and divide by 2 giving 1
     1 is odd  so print 1 and divide by 2 giving 0
     0 reached so stop and read the printing backwards
             from this ^^^ column
```

13 is 1101 in binary

Comment: Depending on architecture and compiler implementation, right-shift by one could be faster. (It certainly won't be slower.)

Comment: It'll print in the right order if you recurse before printing.